# Cannot install nVidia drivers on Ubuntu Studio

Tags: drivers, nvidia

I downloaded NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-331.49.run

within terminal

> cd Downloads
>
> sudo su
>
> sh NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-331.49.run

It gives me the following [http://i.imgur.com/a9W1bRB.png](https://i.imgur.com/a9W1bRB.png)

A quick google search later reveals I need to type

> sudo stop lightdm

to shut off my X server.  Once I type in said command, I get a black screen.

I have read that booting from single user mode from grub may get this working, though I could not do so given the instructions I found.

I'm terribly lost now.

Advice/suggestions?

Thank you.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the output of: `lspci | grep VGA` and a link to the driver with the directions for installing it. Thanks

Comment: 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK107M [GeForce GT 730M] (rev a1)    

http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/73221/en-us     

http://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/331.49/README/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to stop the x server.So that you can be able to install `NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-331.49.run` file.Follow the below steps to install `Nvidia.run` file,

- Login into virtual console <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.
- Go into Downloads directory and install the  .run file,

  ```
  cd ~/Downloads
  sudo su
  sh NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-331.49.run
  ```

Comment: Ctrl+Alt+F1 = black screen

Comment: try F1 to F6,you will surely got virtual console.In my pc,it appears on pressing ctrl+alt+F4

Comment: Ctrl+Alt+F2-F7 were suggested after I googled the problem with Ctrl+Alt+F1 went black.  It did not help.  The screen remains black.  I can only hold down the power button to reboot it.